# openmp parallel for collapse private variable outer loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

Consider the following code run with OpenMP

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    int var; // is this private to execute_thread?
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        execute_thread(i,j);
    }
}
```

Because of the `collapse(2)` clause, this double loop is parallelized and `execute_thread(i,j)` is executed in parallel, for all `i` and `j`. My question is the following: is the variable `var` declared above the inner loop private to each thread, or is it shared for all threads in the inner loop (the `for(int j...)` one)?

Comment: You declare it inside the parallel region so therefore it is private for all threads.

Comment: Thanks, actually I realized now that the loops must be perfectly nested when using the `collapse` clause, i.e. cannot declare anything between the `for` loops, so everything will be indeed private.

Comment: You can collapse manually: for(int i=0; i<100; i++) int i=n/10; int j=n%10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet of code you are showing triggers *undefined behavior*. In fact a *loop-construct* must adhere to some restrictions in order to be conforming (see section 2.7.1 of the [OpenMP 4.0](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) standard). The first of these restrictions in particular reads (emphasis mine):

> All loops associated with the loop construct must be **perfectly nested**;
>   that is, there must be no intervening code nor any OpenMP directive
>   between any two loops.